# MySQL select category and subcategory if they have products

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query which resolves this:

Select main category if it contains product(s) OR it has a subcategory that contains product(s)

the problem is that it doesn't select subcategories with containing products

```
SELECT Category.id, Category.name, Category.description, Category.image
FROM categories_table as Category
JOIN products_table as Product
WHERE Category.subcategory = 0 AND Product.category = Category.id    
    OR Category.id IN
    (
        SELECT SubProduct.categorie
        FROM kosBonusShop_regels AS SubProduct
        WHERE SubProduct.category = Category.subcategory
            AND Product.category = Category.id   
        GROUP BY Product.category
    )
GROUP BY Product.category


Product #1                               Category #1
id             | 1                       id          |  1
category       | 2 (Pencils)             subcategory |  0 (none)
description    | Pencil                  title       |  office supplies

Category #2
id          | 2
subcategory | 1 (office supplies)
title       | Pencils
```

Product Pencil should be in the Category Pencils and Category Pencils should be an Subcategory of the Category Office Supplies

Also the Category Office Supplies Can contain products

Comment: what is possible depth of subcategories?

Comment: You should probably try to avoid using commas in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: Could be that your conditions are not laid out properly. AND always have higher precendence.

Comment: @M0rtiis just one level. Category -> subcategory

Comment: How could `product` have a direct relationship with `category` (as implied by `Product.category`)?

Comment: @Tiny Product.category contains the ID of the Category?

Comment: May be your existing query is creating complex situation, just show your table wise some sample data and what output you required it will easy to understand your requirement.

Comment: in your query perhaps you need to close (Category.subcategory = 0 AND Product.category = Category.id) for better use of OR clause.

Comment: If the relationship traverses through `category->subcategory->product`, then `product` should have a relationship with `subcategory` which in turn have a relationship with `category`. `product` having a direct relationship with `category` is very unlikely.

Comment: @Tiny U're right, it has no connection

Answer (score 1):

You should use IN keyword instead of equal sign when using subquery like this. Also, use of JOIN is preferable in your case. Try this:

```
SELECT Category.id, Category.name, Category.description, Category.image
FROM categories_table as Category
LEFT JOIN products_table as Product ON Product.category = Category.id
WHERE (Category.subcategory = 0 AND NOT ISNULL(Product.id))
    OR Category.id IN
    (
        SELECT SubProduct.categorie
        FROM kosBonusShop_regels AS SubProduct
        WHERE SubProduct.category = Category.subcategory
            AND Product.category = Category.id   
        GROUP BY Product.category
    )
GROUP BY Product.category
```

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem, but it was a good suggestion if the tabel structure was without subcategories. this code doesn't select the main table if it is empty and only has subcategories

Comment: Sorry, can't fully test it at the moment. Corrected my answer, please check this version.

Comment: it's not the point. the OR statement is not solving the query.